# Any particular reason why FaceBook's Subscribe Button isn't showing?

Tags: facebook

I got this FaceBook profile for my upcoming website and I can't get the Subscribe button to show, NOT EVEN ON FaceBook's page!

http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100003492130845

Now, if you go here on FaceBook's page where we build the Subscribe button:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/

And add the above link, it will show nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you've provided is for a person's profile - it looks like you've created a people profile and not a page, hence no subscribe.

//update after comment

Go [here](http://www.facebook.com/about/subscribe) to enable subscribe for your page and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/) to generate a subscribe button for your site.

[image]

Code for subscribe for your page

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/subscribe.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FAxonn-Says%2F372194956141393&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;width=450" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: I also created a page. This one: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Axonn-Says/372194956141393 . And it doesn't work for the page either.

Comment: @Axonn I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ah! So first you have to go and enable Subscribe. Didn't know that! However, it still doesn't work, even though I enabled it ::- (. Not for my profile URL, not for the page either.

Comment: @Axonn That's odd, perhaps you have to have a certain number of likes before they enable subscribe. There does seem to be an entry bar for some of the advanced features.

Comment: @Axonn have a look here http://www.facebook.com/publicfigures and http://www.gogi.in/enable-disable-subscribe-button-facebook.html

Comment: I don't know ::- (. It's very annoying. Definitely something fishy going on there, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @Axonn It's no problem, let me know if you come up with a solution, at least with the generator you can put a subscribe button on your webpage if nothing else. Have you tried looking at the page as a non-admin, could it be that subscribe is only shown to users once enabled?

Comment: I can't add the subscribe button on my web page, that's exactly the problem. It doesn't show. If you go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/ and try to add any of my 2 links (user profile or page) the subscribe box doesn't show AT ALL. The exact same behavior occurs on http://www.axonnsays.com if you go you'll see I have only a big empty space above the Follow @ Twitter button.

Comment: @Axonn oh I see - do you by any chance have the 'disconnect plugin' installed? It works for me so I suspect you have something installed in your browser thats causing the problem.

Comment: I don't have any such plugin installed, and even my AdBlockPlus is disabled. If you are referring to the FaceBook "like" box, that works, yes. But the subscribe does not. Are you telling me that you actually see the "subscribe" ??? So you see BOTH of the facebook buttons? If that's what you're saying, then it's completely weird. I do not see that on FireFox, IE or Opera.

Comment: @Axonn could the two buttons have conflicting javascript? Have you tried adding only the subscribe button?

Comment: Tried it right now. No luck. Still no subscribe. That's exactly how I see it as well. Take a look, I added Mark Zuck's subscribe successfully, TWICE. Mine should be between them. No go ::- (.

Comment: @Axonn, I can see it, it's just subscribing to Mark Zucerberg

Comment: Yeap. Doesn't work for any of my pages. I guess I'm gonna have to find some way of contacting FB.

Comment: StackOverflow posts tagged facebook are effectively facebook's developer support page you might get on better there.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually got to it as well. I posted my question there too.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an AppID ?

> The JavaScript SDK requires that you register your website with Facebook to get an App ID (or appId). The appId is a unique identifier for your site that ensures that we have the right level of security in place between the user and your website. The following example shows how to load the JavaScript SDK once you have your appId:

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Hope this helps

Comment: But wait, I am not making an application. I just need to use the Subscribe button.

Comment: Oh, i tought  that was for "Facebook" for registrations on your website. I forgot the new Facebook "Subscriptions" thingy.

Comment: No biggie. Apparently there's something wrong with my account / or their API. It just doesn't work ::- (. Got to get in touch with them...